# error in the execution of treetagger command tag-eng

Tags: java, windows, perl, batch-file

i 'm trying to do an application in java that use the treetagger.
so tapped this on eclipse

```
String commande="cmd /c  C:\Program Files (x86)\tree-tagger-windows-3.2\TreeTagger\bin\\tag-english"+" "+path;

 Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commande);
```

But it dosesn't work.

I have not much idea about the TreeTagger and to test if I install TreeTagger under windows I typed these commands on the command prompt cd `C: \ Program Files (x86) \ tree-tagger-windows-3.2 \ TreeTagger \ bin` and then

`tag-English nom_de_fichier_à_tagger` but the cmd displays this error message `'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.`

the TreeTagger I install is a zip file I extracted to a folder and I put it in `C: \ Program Files (x86)` is what I did exactly

if I made a mistake during installation can you help me because I too searched the web and I understood nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install a `perl` on windows.  I suggest that you use [`Strawberry Perl`](http://strawberryperl.com/).

I have no experience with TreeTagger, but doing a little googling points to this reference: [`TreeTagger - a language independent part-of-speech tagger`](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/).  Scrolling down there is a Windows version in zip form, that contains an INSTALL.txt which states:

```
Installation
------------

1. Install a Perl interpreter (if you have not already installed one).
   You can download a Perl interpreter for Windows for free at
   http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/

2. Move the TreeTagger directory to the root directory of drive C:.

3. Download the PC parameter files for the languages you need, decompress
   them (e.g. using Winzip or 7zip) and move them to the subdirectory lib.
   Rename the parameter files to <language>.par
   Example: Rename french-par-linux-3.1.bin to french.par

   The UTF8 versions of the parameter files are not supported yet, but
   see below some hints on how to build tagging scripts for the UTF8
   parameter files.

4. Add the path C:\TreeTagger\bin to the PATH environment variable.

5. Open a shell and type the command
   set PATH=C:\TreeTagger\bin;%PATH%

6. Change to the directory C:\TreeTagger

7. Now you can test the tagger, e.g. by analyzing this file with the command
   tag-english INSTALL.txt
```

**Obviously you must've skipped step 1. :)** You could use ActiveState as they suggest, but these days Strawberry perl is a much better option in my opinion.